# Webcam is not working or accessible on Ubuntu 22.04 when using an SSH or Remote Desktop Connection from another machine

Tags: usb, python, webcam, remote-desktop, restricted-access

In this Scenario I connect from an Windows 11 to a Ubuntu 22.04 via local network to run some python scripts, one of these scripts needs webcam access.

Webcams works fine when connected and used locally from either machine. So running "Camera" on Windows and running "Cheese" on Ubuntu both gives access to the webcams and can show an image.

Problem is that I cannot start or access the USB webcams once I tunnel to the Ubuntu machine, it does not matter if I use SSH or RDC (Remote Desktop Connection).

Writing `lsusb` in the terminal I can see all USB devices, and I can also see the webcams, that I am unable to start.

Comment: For me the problem was the shutter was closed. 
Please see this: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-in/inspiron-14-5410-2-in-1-laptop/inspiron-5410-2-in-1-setup-and-specifications/using-the-privacy-shutter?guid=guid-514df42a-261e-493a-9ddb-08f3d2e3b8ab&lang=en-us

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the cameras were owned by 'root', and thus my remote desktop connection user profile did not have access to them even though it is the same user profile I use when logging in locally. :|

### Solution

Transfer ownership of camera to the user profile used in the remote desktop connection

In the terminal check all your cameras using `ls -l /dev/video*` which shows All cams.
changing `ls -l /dev/video4` makes it specific to camera on index 4. this shows:

> `crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 8 Sep 11 11:46 /dev/video4`

change it to

```
sudo chown SomeProfileUsedWithRemote:video /dev/video4
sudo chmod 660 /dev/video4
```

which yeilds

> `crw-rw----+ 1 SomeProfileUsedWithRemote video 81, 8 Sep 11 11:47 /dev/video4`

Voila.
Now I can access the webcams over SSH and RDC! I just have to change from 'root' to remote 'user profile' (for each camera index).